# pandas how to 'get_dummies' on time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science

If I had some time series data: (make some up)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)
```

How could I utilize `get_dummies`? Just looking at the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), I dont know if I can apply to how I am making one hot encoding.

For example, the only way I know how to make a dummy variable to represent time-of-week variables is a very clunky redundant code method. Can someone give me advise on how to do this better?

```
#create dummy variables
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['day_of_week'] = df.index.dayofweek
df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')

df['hour_0'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([0]), 1, 0)
df['hour_1'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([1]), 1, 0)
df['hour_2'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([2]), 1, 0)
df['hour_3'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([3]), 1, 0)
df['hour_4'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([4]), 1, 0)
df['hour_5'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([5]), 1, 0)
df['hour_6'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([6]), 1, 0)
df['hour_7'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([7]), 1, 0)
df['hour_8'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([8]), 1, 0)
df['hour_9'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([9]), 1, 0)
df['hour_10'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([10]), 1, 0)
df['hour_11'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([11]), 1, 0)
df['hour_12'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([12]), 1, 0)
df['hour_13'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([13]), 1, 0)
df['hour_14'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([14]), 1, 0)
df['hour_15'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([15]), 1, 0)
df['hour_16'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([16]), 1, 0)
df['hour_17'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([17]), 1, 0)
df['hour_18'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([18]), 1, 0)
df['hour_19'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([19]), 1, 0)
df['hour_20'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([20]), 1, 0)
df['hour_21'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([21]), 1, 0)
df['hour_22'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([22]), 1, 0)
df['hour_23'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([23]), 1, 0)

df['monday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([0]), 1, 0)
df['tuesday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([1]), 1, 0)
df['wednesday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([2]), 1, 0)
df['thursday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([3]), 1, 0)
df['friday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([4]), 1, 0)
df['saturday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([5]), 1, 0)
df['sunday'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([6]), 1, 0)

df['january'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([1]), 1, 0)
df['february'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([2]), 1, 0)
df['march'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([3]), 1, 0)
df['april'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([4]), 1, 0)
df['may'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([5]), 1, 0)
df['june'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([6]), 1, 0)
df['july'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([7]), 1, 0)
df['august'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([8]), 1, 0)
df['september'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([9]), 1, 0)
df['october'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([10]), 1, 0)
df['november'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([11]), 1, 0)
df['december'] = np.where(df['month'].isin([12]), 1, 0)

df['year19'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2019]), 1, 0)
df['year20'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2020]), 1, 0)
df['year21'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2021]), 1, 0)
df['year22'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2022]), 1, 0)
df['year23'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2023]), 1, 0)
df['year24'] = np.where(df['year'].isin([2024]), 1, 0)
```

And then my final dataframe which I am experimenting with ML algorithms would be:

```
df2 = df[['Temperature', 'Value', 
            'hour_0' , 'hour_1' , 'hour_2' , 'hour_3' , 'hour_4' , 'hour_5' , 'hour_6' ,
            'hour_7' , 'hour_8' , 'hour_9' , 'hour_10' , 'hour_11' , 'hour_12' , 'hour_13' , 
            'hour_14' , 'hour_15' , 'hour_16' , 'hour_17' , 'hour_18' , 'hour_19' , 'hour_20' , 
            'hour_21' , 'hour_22' , 'hour_23' , 
            'monday' , 'tuesday' , 'wednesday' , 'thursday' , 'friday' , 'saturday' , 'sunday' , 
            'january' , 'february' , 'march' , 'april' , 'may' , 'june' , 'july' , 'august' , 
            'september' , 'october' , 'november' , 'december' , 
            'year19' , 'year20' , 'year21' , 'year22' , 'year23' , 'year24']]
```

***EDIT***
UPDATED CODE ATTEMPT

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 50000,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value'], index=tidx)

df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')
df['day_of_week'] = df.index.dayofweek
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year

hour_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['hour'], prefix='hour')

day_mapping = {0: 'monday', 1: 'tuesday', 2: 'wednesday', 3: 'thursday', 4: 'friday', 5: 'saturday', 6: 'sunday'}
day_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['day_of_week'].map(day_mapping))

month_mapping = {0: 'jan', 1: 'feb', 2: 'mar', 3: 'apr', 4: 'may', 5: 'jun', 6: 'jul',
                 7: 'aug', 8: 'sep', 9: 'oct', 10: 'nov', 11: 'dec'}
month_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['month'].map(month_mapping))

year_mapping = {0: 'year_2019', 1: 'year_2020', 2: 'year_2021', 3: 'year_2022', 4: 'year_2023', 5: 'year_2024'}
year_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['year'].map(year_mapping))

df = df.join(hour_dummies)
df = df.join(day_dummies)
df = df.join(month_dummies)
df = df.join(year_dummies)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the corresponding information from the time index, then use `pd.get_dummies`. For example

```
# day name
day_names = pd.get_dummies(df.index.day_name())

# hours
hours = pd.get_dummies(df.index.hour, prefix='hour')

# months
months = pd.get_dummies(df.index.month_name())

# year
years = pd.get_dummies(df.index.year, prefix='year')
```

And then `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat((df, hours, day_names), axis=1)
```

Comment: when I run the code and view it its all NaN, and for some reason the time stamp is 1970

Answer (score 0):

You described the solution exactly in the name of your question:

```py
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['hour'], prefix='hour')
                     hour_0  hour_1  hour_2  hour_3  hour_4  hour_5  hour_6  hour_7  hour_8  ...  hour_15  hour_16  hour_17  hour_18  hour_19  hour_20  hour_21  hour_22  hour_23
2019-01-01 00:00:00       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2019-01-01 01:00:00       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2019-01-01 02:00:00       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2019-01-01 03:00:00       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2019-01-01 04:00:00       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
...                     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
2024-09-14 03:00:00       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2024-09-14 04:00:00       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2024-09-14 05:00:00       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2024-09-14 06:00:00       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2024-09-14 07:00:00       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

As for days of the week/months, use `pandas.Series.map` to replace the values to their "readable" counterparts, then call `pandas.get_dummies`:

```py
day_mapping = {0: 'monday', 1: 'tuesday', 2: 'wednesday', 3: 'thursday', 4: 'friday', 5: 'saturday', 6: 'sunday'}
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['day_of_week'].map(day_mapping)))
```

Comment: I created an EDIT portion for my answer with attempting to get the code to work.. It still looks like some redundant coding... And I also cannot get the `year_dummies` to work properly would you be able to give me some tips still?

Comment: @HenryHub in the case of year, you can use the same method than for hour but with another prefix instead of mapping and it should be working as you want. Then for month, the value for 'jan' is not 0 but 1, so you should add 1 to each value to map: `{1:'jan', 2: 'feb', etc..}`