# access the element in the for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im segregating my dataframe according to  year and month but I want to make it more automatic. Right now I have to hard code them:

```
def year_month_open(c):
   c.Opened_Date.astype('string')
   x = c.Opened_Date.strftime('%Y-%m')

return x

df['year_month'] = df.apply(year_month_open,axis=1)`

Feb20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-02']
Mar20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-03']
Apr20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-04']
May20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-05']
Jun20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-06']
Jul20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-07']
Aug20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-08']
Sep20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-09']
Oct20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-10']
Nov20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-11']
Dec20 = df[df['year_month']=='2020-12']
Jan21 = df[df['year_month']=='2021-01']
Feb21 = df[df['year_month']=='2021-02']
Mar21 = df[df['year_month']=='2021-03']
```

Can you suggest a way to prevent having to code them, such that when I appended another dataset for the following month, I dont have to type

Apr21 = Mar21 = df[df['year_month']=='2021-04']

Comment: You're manually creating binary dummies `Feb20.,...,Mar21` for all possible year-month combinations. [`pd_get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) does that: convert categorical variable to dummy/indicator variables. You can automate this, and as answer says you possibly don't need to do this - why are you doing this is, for classification or regression?

Comment: See e.g. [pandas how to 'get_dummies' on time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61124647/202229). You just want to call `pd.get_dummies` on `df['year_month']`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you consider whether you actually need to do this, or whether another solution such as a function would be more appropriate. For instance, if you use a multi-index with the month-year string as an index, you can just do `df['Apr21']` rather than creating a separate dataframe. If you want to create separate variable, there's the following, but keep in mind that you should be careful with the `eval` function (if a command gets into the `year_month` column, that can be very dangerous).

```
import calendar

def convert_date(date)
    year = date[:4]
    month_num = date[4:]
    month = calendar.month_name[int(month_num)][:3]
    return month+year

for group in df.groupby(year_month):
    month_name = convert_date(group[0])
    month_df = group[1]
    eval("{} = month_df".format(month_name))
```